# Hour calculation based on date excel

Tags: excel, date, time, calculator

I've got a question where I don't know were to start to be honest. 
I want to add a function to my sheet where I calculate the total amount of hours based on the date. 
So as for my example I want excel to recognize the different dates, regardless of their position, and calculate the amount of hours spent on that date.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fjB0.png]

Is that something that is even possible? 
Or is it impossible and is that the reason why I can't find anything about it?
little note: I'm using excel 2016

---

*29-06-2021 update*
got it working with both SUMIFS and SUMIF using the following formula:
=SOMMEN.ALS(B234:B332; A234:A332;"28-06-21")
the current challenge I'm facing is that I want excel to look up the date and determine the day 
I already tried with VLOOKUP (with a calendar on another sheet) but that doesn't seem to work 
Excel has to use the date in the date column to determine which day it is so I can determine the amount of hours per weekday.
[example VLOOKUP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwpXI.png)
Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what

Comment: 23.6 have 3 different hours. The hours difference is depends on... (what cell/info/preset)?

Comment: You can calculate the sum of hours spent on a given date with `=SUMIFS(hours_column, date_column, given_date)`. In Excel 365 you could use `UNIQUE` to get an unique list of dates that occur in your date_column and use these as the given_dates in above formula.

Comment: the hours depend on the amount of time spent on a project and is anywhere between 0,1 and 24
hours are in decimal (so 0,25 is 15 minutes)

Comment: You want a pivot table or to use the `SUMIF` function.

Comment: Since you are representing the hours using a decimal notation (i.e. 90 minutes are represented as 1,5 instead of 01:30) just add the numbers using [SUMIFS function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it running with specifying multiple criteria in the SUMIF function
I now use the following formula for Mondays which basically is a list of all Mondays in a year

```
=SOM(SOM.ALS(A218:A316;{"04-01-21”;”11-01-21”;”18-01-21”;”25-01-21”;”01-02-21”;”08-02-21”;”15-02-21”;”22-02-21”;”01-03-21”;”08-03-21”;”15-03-21”;”22-03-21”;”29-03-21”;”05-04-21”;”12-04-21”;”19-04-21”;”26-04-21”;”03-05-21”;”10-05-21";"17-05-21";"24-05-21";"31-05-21";"07-06-21";"14-06-21";"21-06-21";"28-06-21";"05-07-21";"12-07-21";"19-07-21";"26-07-21";"02-08-21";"09-08-21";"16-08-21";"23-08-21";"30-08-21";"06-09-21";"13-09-21";"20-09-21";"27-09-21";"04-10-21";"11-10-21";"18-10-21";"25-10-21";"01-11-21";"08-11-21";"15-11-21";"22-11-21";"29-11-21";"06-12-21";"13-12-21";"20-12-21";"27-12-21"};B218:B316))
```

SOM=SUM and SOM.ALS=SUMIF in English versions
This works for me, it just takes some time to get all the dates in the formula.